# Android popBackStack shows fragment not added to the backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

`MainFragment` launches `FragA` that launches `FragB` that lunches `FragC`.

Back button press on `FragB` should go to `FragA` and back press on `FragC` should also go to `FragA`.
`FragB` is the only one where `isToAddToBackStack` is `false`.

```
childFragmentManager.commit {
        replace(containerViewId, fragment, fragment::class.java.name)

        if (isToAddToBackStack) {
            addToBackStack(backStateName)
        }
    }
```

Whenever the back button is pressed on `FragC`, `FragB` is shown:

```
if (childFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 1) {
                childFragmentManager.popBackStack()
                return
}
```

What's the better way to achieve the navigation that I'm expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Fragment transactions can involve two different types of tags. The one that most Android developers are familiar with is the Fragment tag, which you can use to find a specific Fragment in your FragmentManager later via `findFragmentByTag()`. This is useful for finding a Fragment when your application is in a particular state, but keep in mind that the Fragment needs to be added to your FragmentManager. If you have `removed()` or `replaced()` a Fragment and haven’t added it to the back stack, you won’t be able to find it.

The other type of tag is the BackStackRecord’s name passed into `addToBackStack()`. This name identifies a particular back stack record, which is a record of what occurred in a particular transaction. `popBackStackImmediate()` and its counterparts have variants that accept a back stack record name to pop the back stack to a particular state.

```
   //fm is FragmentManager
  // Fragment a is on the screen
     Fragment a = new A_Fragment()
     fm.beginTransaction()
       .remove(null /*no fragments in R.id.content*/)
       .add(R.id.content, aFragment, "fragment-a")
       .commit();


   // user wants to go from A to B
     Fragment bFragment = new B_Fragment();
     fm.beginTransaction()
       .remove(fm.findFragmentById(R.id.content)) 
       .add(R.id.content, bFragment, "fragment-b")
       .addToBackStack("a")
       .commit();

   // user wants to go from B to C
       fm.beginTransaction()
         .remove(fm.findFragmentById(R.id.content)) 
         .add(R.id.content, new C_Fragment(), "fragment-c")
         .commit();
```